# ¿Cómo actualizar php5 a php7 en OSX Sierra?

Tags: php, php5, php7, macos

Acabo de seguir este tutorial para actualizar *php5* a *php7* ([Update PHP on Mac OS X](https://jason.pureconcepts.net/2016/09/upgrade-php-mac-os-x/)), pero aunque en la carpeta **usr/local** me crea la carpeta **php5-7.0.12-20161101-102255**, cuando le pregunto al terminal qué versión de *PHP* tengo instalada, me dice que la *5.6.25* y no sé cómo actualizarla.

Comment: Yo te aconsejaría que lo [actualizaras usando Homebrew](https://developerjack.com/blog/2016/08/26/Installing-PHP71-with-homebrew/). Es mucho más sencillo y práctico.

Comment: que pasos seguiste para actualizarlo, puedes contarnos que haz intentado?

Comment: Hola @sioesi Pues básicamente he ejecutado este comando curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.0 que es que ha hecho que se creara la carpeta usr/local/php5-7.0.12-20161101-102255.

Comment: @kerunaru cuando ejecuto el comando brew unlink php56 recibo este error: Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/php56. No he usado nunca este gestor de paquetes y no se muy bien a que se debe. Yo ya tengo instalado php 5 pero homebrew parece que lo busca dentro de su propia carpeta de instalación?. Una cosa que observo es que yo tengo la carpeta usr/local/php5 pero la carpeta php5 tiene una flechita que entiendo es un acceso directo lo que no se es a donde?

Comment: https://jason.pureconcepts.net/2016/09/upgrade-php-mac-os-x/ echa un vistazo a este link, esta en ingles pero hay mas pasos a seguir que solo instalar php

Comment: @kerunaru acabo de instalar debut con hombres y ahora si que me aparece el directorio usr/local/cellar/php5 curiosamente. Con lo cual ahora si me funciona el comando breaw unlink 56. Seguido ejecuto el comando brea install php70 y se me crea la carpeta usr/local/cellar/php70 pero php--version me sigue dando la 5.6.

Comment: ¿Has iniciado una nueva sesión en el terminal? Es posible que no se haya actualizado el `$PATH` para tu sesión actual...

Comment: @kerunaru exacto. He tenido que añadir al Path la ruta donde homebrew instala php70, es decir, usr/local/Cellar/php70 y ahora php --version me detecta la 7. Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Creo que ya he encontrado y entendido la solución.

Una vez instalado con `homebrew php7` y por lo tanto se ha creado la carpeta `/usr/local/Cellar/php70`, lo que hay que hacer es teniendo en el `$PATH` la ruta `/usr/local/bin`, ahí hay un fichero **php** que es un enlace simbólico a la carpeta **php** de la versión a utilizar.

Es decir, si ese enlace simbólico apunta a `/usr/local/Cellar/php70 php --version` te dará *la versión 7*, pero no hace falta añadir la ruta `/usr/local/Cellar/php70` al `$PATH`.